# Play again feature not working in program

Tags: python, function, recursion

I've written a beginner program to play a game. The main structure of the program nests various functions within an outer, parent function. I had a question about calling `fparent()` from within `fnested()`.

NOTE: Sadly I cannot share the original code as this is for university and due to academic integrity policies I cannot make the code public.

The idea behind the implementation is that if a user wants to repeat the program, they should input a valid indicator, `YES`. This happens within a nested function. The program seeks to recognise this input and thus call `fparent()` once more, re-starting the program.

This is currently not working.

- I wanted to know if there is a way to code this feature

Links to existing answers are most welcome as I couldn't find anything that helped me directly with this.

Comment: Sorry, your redacted code doesn't make any sense. How could `if True` ever be false, to trigger the else?

Comment: without proper `return` from function you will get stack overflow fatal error. That is better if you do not ask about your current code. Ask about the task you want to complete. And we will help you with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tried to call the parent function directly from nested it will give you "stack overflow" maximum depth reached.

As you stated the problem :

> they should input a valid indicator, YES. This happens within a
>   nested function. The program seeks to recognise this input and thus
>   call fparent() once more, re-starting the program.

You can try something like this:

```
def f0():
    def f1():
        print("do some stuff in function f1")
    def f2():
        print("do some stuff in function f2")
    def f3():
        print("do some stuff with function f3")

    user_input=str(input("Do you want to repeat the program Yes or No  >> "))
    map_userinput={"Yes":f0,"Level2":f2,"Level3":f3}
    if user_input=="Yes":
        print("ok calling the parent function from nested function")
        map_userinput[user_input]()

    elif user_input=="Level2":
        map_userinput[user_input]()

    else:
        print("continue with this nested function")


f0()
```